# Specify an SQL username other than dbo in Code First Entity Framework ( C# ASP.NET MVC 3 )

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server 2008 database in a shared hosting environment from C# from within an ASP.NET MVC 3 application connecting via EF (code first).

My problem is that the generated `SELECT` statement looks like so:

```
SELECT ... FROM [dbo].[TableName]
```

which throws the error `Invalid object name`, but works fine when I do:

```
SELECT ... FROM [mySQLUserName].[TableName]
```

How do I specify a username other than `dbo` (e.g. `mySQLUserName`)?

---

**EDIT:**

The closest articles I have found that are relevant to this issue are:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

with specific emphasis on the second article, however it doesn't specify how to set a username other than `dbo`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the schema using a property on the `TableAttribute` that decorates your entity classes.

```
[Table("TableName", Schema = "mySQLUserName")]
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius!

You know, this is actually a much better answer than the one provided for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399443/entityframework-using-wrong-tablename

Comment: The `OnModelCreating`/`ToTable` solution is good for more advanced mapping scenarios, but since you know the schema name at compile time, the simple option should work just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to set this globally? EF uses dbo by deafult wihtout us specyfing it.. so annoying changing all my classes

Comment: @ppumkin check [the answer by Bill below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26549837/148412).

Answer (score 7):

You don't say which version of EF you're using.  If you're using Code First (4.1) you can specify the schema on a table attribute:

```
[Table("Users", Schema = "myschema")]
public class User { .. }
```

You can use Scott's article (the second one) as a basis, but you add an additional parameter.  ie.:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().ToTable("TableName", "SchemaName");
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that the `ToTable` method was overloaded to allow specification of a schema name. Very useful!

Comment: This will ruin pluralization.

Answer (score 7):

With EF6, you can now do this.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("logs");  //set default schema
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LogMap());
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old, but I came across it in my research and came up with a solution that may benefit others, and have discussed it privately with @ppumkin.

The schema name can be passed as a string to the ToTable() method, so essentially using a member of the containing class instead of a hard-coded value allows you to dynamically specify the schema name upon context creation.

This is a dumbed down version of what I have:

```
public class FooDbContext : DbContext
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }

    static FooDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FooDbContext>(null);
    }

    public FooDbContext(string schemaName)
        : base("name=connString1")
    {
        this.SchemaName = schemaName;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new City_Map(this.SchemaName));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Customer_Map(this.SchemaName));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerSecurity_Map(this.SchemaName));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

}
```

And the mapping abstract class:

```
public abstract class SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration(string schemaName)
        : base()
    {
        this.SchemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public new void ToTable(string tableName)
    {
        base.ToTable(tableName, SchemaName);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class City_Map : SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public City_Map(string schemaName)
        : base(schemaName)
    {
        ToTable("City");
        HasKey(t => t.Code);

        Property(t => t.Code)
            .HasColumnType("integer")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.CityName)
            .HasColumnName("City")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(t => t.State)
            .HasMaxLength(2);
    }
}
```

The key thing to note here is the `ToTable()` method in `SchemaNameEntityConfiguration`. It overrides the superclass' method so when the implementations call `ToTable(tableName)` it supplies the schema name as well.

*Important note: `EntityTypeConfiguration.ToTable()` is non-virtual, and the abstract `SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration` hides that method with its own and thus won't be called virtually if the `_Map` object is type as `EntityTypeConfiguration`.

It was one concern of mine but there's an easy (and only slightly annoying) work around: instead of implementing a base class that supplies it automatically, just ensure in the `_Map` classes you pass the `schemaName` to `ToTable()`.

*Usage:*

```
using (FooDbContext context = new FooDbContext("theSchemaName"))
{
    foreach (
        var customer in context.Customers
                .Include(c => c.City)
            .Where(c => c.CustomerName.StartsWith("AA"))
            .OrderBy(c => c.CustomerCode)
        )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:20}: {1} - {2}, {3}",
            customer.CustomerCode,
            customer.CustomerName,
            customer.City.CityName,
            customer.City.State));
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested using multiple contexes within the same program. It shouldn't have an issue, but if the DbContext caches the model at a static class level (rather than at the instance-level), it could be a problem. That may be resolved by creating separate subclasses of the context though, each specifying a different schema name.

Comment: Thank you ! and waht a spectacular answer that is +1  +beer

Answer (score 3):

You can either decorate your class with the [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.tableattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and specify the Schema, or you could try what this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b4d59f19-bdec-4b7a-b63a-299c658af40d) describes.