# Invalid Object Name Exception When Accessing Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have `domain` server with `database`. When I run `aspx` page through server, it gives me exception.

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Employees'.
```

In my database Employees table the name **don't start with dbo**. It start with `sky.Employees`. I think that this might be the problem.

aspx code behind:

```
skyfi_PeopleEntities context = new skyfi_PeopleEntities();
            GridView1.DataSource = (from c in context.Employees
                                    select c).ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

In this code I think ADO.NET EF works with default **dbo.** name. The exception may come from here. Is it possible to change from the default **dbo.** to **sky.** in the settings of the current `skyfi_PeopleEntities`. What should I do to fix this problem with the exception ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184577/specify-an-sql-username-other-than-dbo-in-code-first-entity-framework-c-sharp

Comment: As AshReva has mentioned, are you using code-first, model-first..?

Comment: Yes I am using code first. In local server I don't have problem but when I run it through hosting server, the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that is because due to invalid connection string, I suggest you also try to call table with simple name.

sky.Employees or dbo.Employees is not the reasons of error.

Can you show your connection string to us. Furthermore also try to call table with simple name (MyTable1) than try sky.Employees

Thanks